# Choose number of labels on contourplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, contour

I looked up through [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) and [examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html) of contour plot of matplotlib and perhaps missed what I am asking now.

I have a contour plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline

import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, cos, sin, sinh, cosh
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# values x, y
delta = 0.025
X = np.arange(0, 6, delta)
Y = np.arange(-1, 0.2, delta)

I = 1j  # imaginary unit
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
# really huge expr.
AA = (0.1743261076e-2-0.1743261076e-2*I)*sin(x)*(exp(1.414213562+.7071067812*I+(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)+0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))-1.*exp(-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x)-.7071067812*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))+(3.887320974*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(2.366831780*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(2.022482447*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(3.321756325*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.6752336213*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y+4.178862074*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-1.318639968*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y+4.022439224*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-(1.318639968*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(4.022439224*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(.6752336213*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(4.178862074*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(.6752336213*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-(4.022439224*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-(1.318639968*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-2.022482447*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+2.366831780*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+4.178862074*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-1.318639968*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+4.022439224*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.6752336213*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(4.178862074*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-3.321756325*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+3.887320974*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x)))/(cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*(-(.8189270221*I)*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(.9583581328*I)*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(.4986113867*I)*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(.5835053242*I)*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.4986113867*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-.5835053242*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.8189270221*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-.9583581328*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

AA_masked = np.ma.array(AA.real, mask = (y > 0.1*cos(x)))

CS = ax.contour(x, y, AA_masked.real, 25)

ax.clabel(CS, inline=True, fontsize=10, manual=None)

x_threshold = np.linspace(0, 6, 1000)
y_threshold = 0.1*np.cos(x_threshold)
ax.plot(x_threshold, y_threshold, linestyle = '--', color = 'black')

ax.set_xlabel(r'x')
ax.set_ylabel(r'y')

plt.show()
```

that is working great and plots:

[image]

But I need to limit **number of labels**, **not number of contours**.

So, I need to get all 25 contours which is fourth parameters here

```
CS = ax.contour(x, y, AA_masked.real, 25)
```

but to limit numbers of digits on my plot. So in the end I would like to get each let's say third label on my plot keeping all contours:

[image]

Hopefully, I stated my issue clear. So which parameter should I pass to limit number of labels on contourplot in matplotlib?

Thank you very much in advance!

**EDIT 1**

It is possible to achieve it with [clabel](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clabel.html), but in that case I need to know the values of labels. Sometimes I do not know the real values of contour so that approach is not okay for me

Comment: You can specify the levels to be labeled in `clabel`: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clabel.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Please, see Edit 1

Comment: The levels are stored in `CS.levels`, so just do `ax=clabel(cs, levels=cs.levels[::5])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jody Klymak correctly stated in the comments sections, one may specify the levels to be labeled in [clabel](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clabel.html) and since the levels are stored in `cs.levels` there is no need to know the exact values of levels and adding `ax=clabel(cs, levels=cs.levels[::5])` does the job.

So the working code is:

```
%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline

import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt, cos, sin, sinh, cosh
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# values x, y
delta = 0.025
X = np.arange(0, 6, delta)
Y = np.arange(-1, 0.2, delta)

I = 1j  # imaginary unit
x, y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
# really huge expr.
AA = (0.1743261076e-2-0.1743261076e-2*I)*sin(x)*(exp(1.414213562+.7071067812*I+(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)+0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))-1.*exp(-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x)-.7071067812*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))+(3.887320974*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(2.366831780*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(2.022482447*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(3.321756325*I)*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.6752336213*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y+4.178862074*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-1.318639968*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y+4.022439224*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-(1.318639968*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(4.022439224*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(.6752336213*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(4.178862074*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+(.6752336213*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-(4.022439224*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-(1.318639968*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-2.022482447*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+2.366831780*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+4.178862074*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-1.318639968*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+4.022439224*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.6752336213*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(4.178862074*I)*cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*y-3.321756325*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+3.887320974*sinh(.7071067812*y+(.7071067812*I)*y-(0.7071067812e-1*I)*cos(x)-0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x)))/(cosh((0.7071067812e-1+0.7071067812e-1*I)*(10.+cos(x)))*(-(.8189270221*I)*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(.9583581328*I)*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(.4986113867*I)*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-(.5835053242*I)*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.4986113867*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-.5835053242*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*sinh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))+.8189270221*sin(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))-.9583581328*cos(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))*cosh(0.7071067812e-1*cos(x))))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

AA_masked = np.ma.array(AA.real, mask = (y > 0.1*cos(x)))

CS = ax.contour(x, y, AA_masked.real, 25)

ax.clabel(CS, levels=CS.levels[::2], inline=True, fontsize=10, manual=None)

x_threshold = np.linspace(0, 6, 1000)
y_threshold = 0.1*np.cos(x_threshold)
ax.plot(x_threshold, y_threshold, linestyle = '--', color = 'black')

ax.set_xlabel(r'x')
ax.set_ylabel(r'y')

plt.show()
```

which gives the pleasant outcome:
[image]